# Flutter Firebase Messaging Stream Listener with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, riverpod

I'm new to flutter and I'm building an app using Firebase Messaging and Riverpod for state management. I've followed this tutorial for utilizing Riverpod to handle the initialization of global listeners from main.dart and help abstract them into their own classes.

https://codewithandrea.com/articles/riverpod-initialize-listener-app-startup/

However the event handler for the `ref.listen` does not get fired when a new FCM message is sent.  If I register a listener directly on the `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage` stream, the listener fires.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with riverpod to cause it not to fire.

```
//StreamProvider<RemoteMessage>
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
Stream<RemoteMessage> fcmOnMessage(FcmOnMessageRef ref) {
  return FirebaseMessaging.onMessage;
}
```

```
class NotificationService {
  NotificationService(this.ref) {
    _init();
  }

  final Ref ref;

  void _init() {
    
    //When directly subscribing to the stream this listener is fired
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');

      if (message.notification != null) {
        print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
      }
    });

    //This does not add a listener to the stream
    ref.listen(fcmOnMessageProvider, (previous, next) { 
      final remoteMessage = next.value;

      debugPrint("onForegroundMessage: ${remoteMessage?.notification?.title}");
      debugPrint("onForegroundMessage: ${remoteMessage?.notification?.body}");
    });
    
  }
}

@riverpod
NotificationService notificationService(NotificationServiceRef ref) {
  return NotificationService(ref);
}
```

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.setAutoInitEnabled(true);
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true
  );
  
  final container = ProviderContainer();
  container.read(notificationServiceProvider);

  runApp(
    UncontrolledProviderScope(
      container: container,
      child: const MyApp(),
    )
  );
}
```